# two updates on same line with ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm trying to work on a same object but I can't do 2 times again an update after an another:

```
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    Dao<Demandes, Integer> demandesDao = null;
    demandesDao = db.getDemandesDao();
    UpdateBuilder<Demandes,Integer> updateBuilder = demandesDao.updateBuilder();

    updateBuilder.where().eq("id", demande.getId());

    updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("statutEnvoieSendLead", 1);


    updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("dateEnvoieSendLead", new Date());
    updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("contactWebId", slr.getOption().getContactWebID());
    updateBuilder.update();


    GoogleAnalytics ga = new GoogleAnalytics(getActivity());
    ga.envoieTracker(idApplication, demandeId, logement, typeForm);


    XMLSendSimulation xmlSendSimulation = new XMLSendSimulation(slr.getOption().getContactWebID());
    xml = XMLGenerator.GenerateSendSimulationXml(xmlSendSimulation);
    updateBuilder.where().eq("id", demande.getId());
    updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("xmlSimulation", xml);
    updateBuilder.update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to work on a same object but I can't do 2 times again an update after an another:

It would have been helpful for you to share the exception that was generated when you try your code.  I suspect that you are getting some sort of SQL exception?

The problem is that `UpdateBuilder` doesn't forget the previous information after `update()` is called.  You can use [`updateBuilder.reset()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/StatementBuilder.html#reset()) to have it forget about the previous `eq(...)` and `updateColumnValue(...)` calls or just create a new `UpdateBuilder` instance.  Without the `reset()` you are just adding to the previous calls.

Comment: So I can't work on a same object ? I have to reset if I wan't to do an update after an another ?

Comment: There's many things you can do @Ben but you need to show the exception for me to be able to help.  It also would be helpful to say what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The problem is because of my xml and single quote, help me here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368307/updatebuilder-and-pass-an-xml